# Time complexity of DFS in undirected graph

Tags: graph, time-complexity, depth-first-search

Lets say we have 4 nodes and all nodes are connected to all other nodes, and I need to go from node1 to node4. Most resources i check the time complexity is `O(V+E)`, but I am kind of confused.

```
                            node1 
                              |
         node2      /       node3       /        node4     level2     3
           | 
  node1 / node3 / node4      ..................            level3     3 to power of 2
```

so complexity is N to the power of N if all node will be visited. Even using a hashset to keep track of which nodes have been visited using backtracking, it should not impact the overall time complexity?

Comment: Did my answer help answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

The complexity would not be *N<sup>N</sup>* if you visit all nodes from each node, it would be *N<sup>2</sup>*, if *N* here is your number of nodes.

Now it so happens that a complete graph (a graph where all nodes are connected to all nodes, like in your example) has a number of edges ***|E| = O(|V|<sup>2</sup>)***. If you don't know why, just note that each node is connected to *(N - 1)* other nodes so the exact number of edges is *(N - 1)<sup>2</sup> = N<sup>2</sup> - 2N + 1 = O(N<sup>2</sup>)*.

The time complexity of Depth-first search is, like you say, *O(|V| + |E|)*. In big-O notation, this is just the same as *O(max(|V|, |E|))*, because only the dominant term will matter. So for our complete graph, *|E|* dominates and the complexity is just *O(|E|)*.

As we previously stated, *|E| = O(|V|<sup>2</sup>)*, so our complexity is *O(|E|) = **O(|V|<sup>2</sup>)***.

Does this provide some clarity to your confusion?